# Installed EV3 software on Win 8 and it won't load

Tags: ev3

EV3 software used to work on my laptop.  Now it does not load any more.  When I double click on the LEGO Mindstorms icon.  It starts the procedure of loading the software.  Then it stuck there and won't go further.  I tried to remove the software and reinstall it.  Nothing helps.  Has anyone else got into this problem before?

Answer (score 1):

A possibility is, that you lack the latest Silverlight update.

I had this problem on some Windows and Mac OS X machines recently.

Maybe you can try to install the latest version: https://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/ I think it's worth a try.

Comment: I actually have the latest version of silverlight on my computer. :(  Thank you for helping.

Comment: Have a look at C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Local\LEGO\MINDSTORMS EV3\crashreports\ if there are any files (crash reports). This path may be a little bit different on Windows 8. This example is from Windows 10.